# How can I solve java lang unsatisfiedlink error when runing jdeveloper?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

[image: Jdeveloper start up error]

I cannot run Jdeveloper. My java is in /usr/java
How can I fix this? I run rpm --query --whatprovides 'libX....' but it says no package provides this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/install-lolibfiles.html) - the answer appears to correspond to your needs. It appears to be more of a progamming question than a DBA one, but we're here to help! :-).

Furthermore, a quick Google of [sudo yum install libXext](https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sudo%20yum%20install%20libxext) got me to this link. Please take the statckexchange site tour and in particular, check out the "help us to help you" blog - both available at the bottom of the page on the left.